# EWS Extended Properties between accounts

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices, outlook-addin

we have encountered a problem with recognizing and setting ExtendedProperties by EWS. Right now, we have the functionality to import emails, which can be done either manually by user or a separate service. There seems to be inconsistency with how Exchange searches through ExtendedProperties and how they are set.

To clarify, I have three mailboxes attached to Outlook application. One is mine and two are the test accounts, which are linked to my AD account. The test accounts contain emails which are imported by the automatic service(when a mail is sent to one of them, it is imported to our application and there is set and ExtendedProperty on the email, providing the information that the email was imported).

What is strange, on my side, in Outlook Add-in, on one account the emails are properly marked and on the other it is not happening as it should, despite that the mechanism is the same.

These are the codes of our add-in.

1. This is the code of retrieving emails:

   ```
   private static IEnumerable<EmailMessage> GetEmails(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder folder, int pageSize, DateTime lastImport)
   {
       SearchFilter filter = PrepareFilter(lastImport);

       List<Item> foundItems = new List<Item>();

       Guid propertySetId = new Guid("F723C954-3F83-46AA-A783-FDEAC90AE512");
       ExtendedPropertyDefinition registered = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(propertySetId, "Registered", MapiPropertyType.Boolean);

       ItemView view = new ItemView(pageSize);
       view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, registered);
       foundItems = service.FindItems(folder.Id, filter, view).Items.ToList();

       List<EmailMessage> results = new List<EmailMessage>();
       foreach (EmailMessage message in foundItems)
       {
           results.Add(message);
       }

       return results;
   }

   private static SearchFilter PrepareFilter(DateTime lastImport)
   {
       Guid propertySetId = new Guid("F723C954-3F83-46AA-A783-FDEAC90AE512");
       ExtendedPropertyDefinition Registered= new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(propertySetId, "Registered", MapiPropertyType.Boolean);

       SearchFilter isRegistered = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(registered, true);

       return isRegistered;
   }
   ```
2. And this is the flag setting method written by my colleague:

   ```
   public static bool SetExchangeRegistered(List<MailItem> mailsToRegister)
   {
       try
       {
           var service = new Exchange.ExchangeService(Exchange.ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010)
           {
               UseDefaultCredentials = true
           };

           var emailAddress = new Application().ActiveExplorer().Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress;
           service.AutodiscoverUrl(emailAddress);

           foreach (var mail in mailsToRegister)
           {
               string itemId = ConvertHexEntryIdToEwsId(service, mail.EntryID, emailAddress);

               Exchange.EmailMessage message = Exchange.EmailMessage.Bind(service, new Exchange.ItemId(itemId));

               bool propertyRegisteredExists =
                   message.ExtendedProperties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PropertyDefinition.Name == "Registered") != null;

               if (!propertyRegisteredExists)
               {
                   Guid propertySetId = new Guid("F723C954-3F83-46AA-A783-FDEAC90AE512");
                   Exchange.ExtendedPropertyDefinition registered =
                       new Exchange.ExtendedPropertyDefinition(propertySetId, "Re", Exchange.MapiPropertyType.Boolean);

                   message.SetExtendedProperty(registered, true);
               }
               else
               {
                   message.ExtendedProperties.First(x => x.PropertyDefinition.Name == "Registered").Value = true;
               }

               message.Update(Exchange.ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
           }
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           grmtAddInBase.Logger.Trace(string.Format("Registered update failed: {0}", ex.Message));
           return false;
       }

       grmtAddInBase.Logger.Trace("Email property 'Registered' updated successfully");
       return true;
   }
   ```

Generally, the method above seems to be identical in control flow to the method which is implemented in the separate service, and it seems that it actually does set the ExtendedProperty of the email correctly.

Another clue, which, to be honest, leaves me clueless, is that even when I tried to get all the emails greedily, load it and then separate the correct ones by their ExtendedProperty which we set... The problem then is that for some emails(i.e. inside one of the mailboxes which are treated by the autoimport service) it sees the Properties correctly and for the rest(i.e. my own mailbox) it doesn't even load and ExtProps, which means that it probably does not see them at all.

I have also tried to use `DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings`, but then it didn't work at all.

I am a little bit puzzled and nobody in close proximity or EWS docs/MS Forums could provide the answer. I am aware that there may be no help, I am aware of the possibility that we are just hopelessly stupid and made some mistake which we cannot find.

After a while, the emails on Exchange mailboxes are just copies - that would be reasonable reason why we cannot access the ExtendedProperties of the email that we received, when it's "flag" was set by another user. But, maybe there is a way to synchronize those properties between those mailboxes? Because there are some alternatives already that we will discuss, but it would be nice if at least part of the current solution could be reused.

Comment: Are you sure these properties actually exist in the messages? Take a look at a problematic message with OutlookSpy (click IMessage button) to see all properties.

Comment: Actually, they doesn't and that is correct. Unfortunately we, the geniuses, omitted the simple fact, that the property is being set after sending the email, so the receiver will not have it on his copy. Therefore I wonder if there is a possibility to synchronize the email information, pulling it from another mailbox as the InternetMessageId is the same for both. I figure there isn't so I'm currently working on entirely different solution, but I'm curious if there actually is the possibility to pull someone else's extProps...